# How To Create a Net Launcher Sound

Tags: shotgun, scifi, weapon

I need some help folks, I have to create the sound of the net launcher, in fact near from the one in the "Fitfh Element" of Luc Besson.

It's a big powerful gun who fires a net over the oppents, So It has to be aggressive.

I've tried some stuff, with big wind gust, whooshes, fire arrows, but I can't manage to create a powerful net launcher sound.

So if there is anybody around who has some tips or ideas, I'll appreciate.

Here the link of the scene from the "The Fitfh Element" in order to give you something to compare : The net launcher is at 1:19

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes you just need to put a bang on it! It may feel like it's not a weapon because we're so used to threatening weapons having a sharp initial sound. I'd add something like that, doesn't even need to be as distinct as a gunshot. Then back it up straight away (literally from when the trigger is pulled) with a *friction* type sound such as the one which makes up the bulk of the example you give - it sounds a lot like a piece of rough material being pulled out from underneath something, maybe with a large zip also being pulled very fast. You could also add in something mechanical like a fast ratchet turn or similar. Then add whoosh elements as a sweetener.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi ! I'v tried few things thtat you've advised me, and they were efficient.

Answer (score 4):

With complex sounds like that I think the best thing to do is break it into its component parts.  What is the sound when it's still (if any).  Trigger sound, firing preload, firing impact, texture or unique sound of firing, net leaving the gun, net through air, net landing.

For me if I breaking it down into smaller sounds is what can it a uniqueness that you cant get with 1 or 2 stock sounds.

Answer (score 2):

Mortars tubes firing can work well as it is something big and heavy moving down a barrel at relatively high speed, very similar to what a net launcher would have to do.  You probably then want to add a sound of the net flying through the air, but I'm not sure how I'd go about trying to get that component of the sound.  You'd finally want it hitting the target which would probably be easiest just to drop a thing of rope and some tent pegs on the floor.

Comment: Hi ! I've tried few things thtat you've advised me, and they were efficient. I've finished with an electric drill backward to give the sense of power coming up with an addition of a Shot  from a mortar (which really works) to give the "pop", accompanied with the sound of blow-gun both for the initial sound , and of course big whooshes. The next Time I will breaking down in order to prepare my ideas. Thanks a lot everybody